# Hamiltonian circuit

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, computational-complexity, computational-geometry, triangulations

Let us consider a disk with one labelled point on the boundary and $n$ labelled points in the interior. 
Let T be a triangulation of the whole disk with vertices on the labelled points such that T contains no self-loops except the boundary of the disk, no multiple edges between two points in the interior of T, arcs of T can be curved.

1) Does T have an Hamiltonian circuit ?

2) If R is another triangulation of the same time, how many flips (as a function of  $ n $ should one perform at most in order to get from R to T ?

Comment: I don't get it.  The face inside and adjacent to the boundary can only be a triangle if its other two edges join the same pair of vertices.  But you ruled out multiple edges..

Comment: You're right. No multiple edges between two points in the interior of the disk. I'll edit.

Answer (score 2):

1. Not necessarily.
2. See the famous paper of Sleator/Tarjan/Thurston (Journal of the AMS, vol 1, issue 1, I believe).

Comment: I know that paper, it's about triangulations of a polygon. Labelled points are inside the disk in my case. Methods used are pure hyperbolic geometry (!)